# How can a contract accept some ether and send a stablecoin in return

Tags: solidity-0.5.x, inheritance, stablecoins

My contract has to take ETH as a collateral and send some stablecoins ( like USDC) to user.
How can I use any stablecoin into my contract , assuming contract has an infinite supply of USDC ?
I too some clue from

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/transfers-and-approval-of-erc-20-tokens-from-a-solidity-smart-contract/

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Loan is USDC {
    
    USDC public usdc;
    
    uint16 price;
    // Manually update price of token to Eth
    function currentPrice(uint16 _price) public {
        price = _price;
    }
    
    function borrow() public payable {
        require ( msg.value > 0 , "You need to send some ether");
        uint amount = msg.value*price*80/100;   // No. of token transfer is 80% of the value of ether
        usdc.transfer(amount);
            
    }
    
    function returnAmt(uint _amount) public payable {
        require (_amount > 0 , "You need to send some token");
        uint ramount = _amount*100/(80*price);
        
        usdc.transfer(address(this), _amount);
        msg.sender.transfer(ramount);
        
        
    }
}
```

Can you please check the error in usage inside functions ?

Comment: What do you mean by "inherit a stablecoin"? I you want USDC, you have to purchase them and transfer them to your contract address. You cannot mint USDC. Only Circle (the issuer of USDC) can.

Comment: Is USDC an address or ERC20 token? As a token its usage is wrong: 1/ `usdc.transfer(amount)` is an ether transfers, 2/ `usdc.transfer(address(this), _amount)` the contract transfers tokens to itself.